# pandas how to drop rows when all float columns are NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df

```py
  AAA BBB CCC DDD  ID1  ID2  ID3  ID4
0 txt txt txt txt  10   NaN  12   NaN
1 txt txt txt txt  10   NaN  12   13
2 txt txt txt txt  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

With the following dtypes

```py
AAA          object
BBB          object
CCC          object
DDD          object
ID1          float64
ID2          float64
ID3          float64
ID4          float64
```

Is there a way to drop rows only when ALL float columns are NaN?

output:

```py
  AAA BBB CCC DDD  ID1  ID2  ID3  ID4
0 txt txt txt txt  10   NaN  12   NaN
1 txt txt txt txt  10   NaN  12   13
```

I can't do it with df.dropna(subset=['ID1','ID2','ID3','ID4']) because my real df has several dynamic floating columns.

Thanks

Comment: Use `isna`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html

Comment: You can't do it with the current df because you didn't use `inplace=True`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for get all float columns, then test for non missing values and select by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for at least one non misisng value per row - so misising floats rows are removed:

```
df1 = df[df.select_dtypes(float).notna().any(axis=1)]
print (df1)
   AAA  BBB  CCC  DDD   ID1  ID2   ID3   ID4
0  txt  txt  txt  txt  10.0  NaN  12.0   NaN
1  txt  txt  txt  txt  10.0  NaN  12.0  13.0
```

Your solution with [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) should be changed for pass float columns and parameter `how='all'` for test if all `NaN`s per rows:

```
df1 = df.dropna(subset=df.select_dtypes(float).columns, how='all')
#for return same dataframe 
#df.dropna(subset=df.select_dtypes(float).columns, how='all', inplace=True)
```

If possible multiple types of floats check by `np.floating`:

```
df1 = df.dropna(subset=df.select_dtypes(np.floating).columns, how='all')
```

Comment: This is answer is flawed because it assumes only float64 dtypes. Check my edit ;p

Comment: @rafaelc - hmmm, if use `df['ID5'] = np.array([1,2,np.nan])` my code working perfect, but if possible multiple `float` types need `print ( df.select_dtypes(include=np.floating).columns.tolist())
`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
df.dropna(subset=df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns, how='all')
```

---

I'd suggest using `include=np.number` because it includes all `float` dtypes - which all may contain `NaN`. When you use `include=float`, you just get the standard `npfloat64` dtype

For illustration:

```
df['ID5'] = np.array([1,2,np.nan], dtype=np.float16)


>>> df.select_dtypes(include=float).columns.tolist()
['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4']

>>> df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns.tolist()
['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4', 'ID5']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `NaN` with`0`and then drop those columns which contain only `NaN`

> `df.loc[:,~df.replace(0,np.nan).isna().all()]`