# Iterate and extract tables from web saving as excel file in Python

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, python-requests, web-crawler, python-3.6

I want to iterate and extract table from the link [here](http://zjj.sz.gov.cn/ztfw/gcjs/xmxx/jgysba/), then save as excel file.

How can I do that? Thank you.

[image: xtra]

My code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

url = 'http://zjj.sz.gov.cn/ztfw/gcjs/xmxx/jgysba/'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
print(soup)
```

New update:

```
from requests import post
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36",
        "Referer": "http://zjj.sz.gov.cn/projreg/public/jgys/jgysList.jsp"}
dfs = []
#dfs = pd.DataFrame()

for page in range(0, 10):
    data = {"limit": 100, "offset": page * 100, "pageNumber": page + 1}
    json_arr = requests.post("http://zjj.sz.gov.cn/projreg/public/jgys/webService/getJgysLogList.json", headers = headers, data = data).text
    d = json.loads(json_arr)
    df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(d['rows']) , orient='list')
    dfs.append(df)
    print(dfs)

dfs = pd.concat(dfs)
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842073/pandas-how-to-drop-rows-when-all-float-columns-are-nan
dfs = dfs.loc[:, ~dfs.replace(0, np.nan).isna().all()]
dfs.to_excel('test.xlsx', index = False)
```

It generates `10` pages and `1000` rows, but some columns values are misplaced, someone knows where did I do wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Did you write any code to get this data? if you did, please post it with question along with the problem faced, if any.

Comment: Yea, as must know you can't get javascript injected data via `bs4`. But if you look in Network tab there's a JSON API with all the paginated data. You can use that to directly get the data you want.

Comment: Could you help modify the code? @ans2human

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, using the `JSON` **API** from **XHR** you make a simple python `post` request via `requests` and you have your data.

In the params you have two of them which you can change to get different volumes of data, `limit` is the nos of objects you get in a request. `pageNumber` is the paginated page counter.

```
from requests import post
import json

url = 'http://zjj.sz.gov.cn/projreg/public/jgys/webService/getJgysLogList.json'
data = { 'limit' : '100', 'pageNumber' : '1'}
response = post(url, data=d)
response.text
```

Further you can use `pandas` to create a data frame or create a excel as you want.

Comment: Thank you, I update my complete code, but the result seems not correct, could u check where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: yea sure, lemme check.

Comment: Just wonder if you have found any problems in my code? @ans2human

Comment: So i see you're getting the required data! what's not working? Dataframe construction?

Comment: It seems works, but I feel not certain if should use `append` and `concat`.

Comment: can you create a new question for converting this data to dataframe then to excel?

Comment: http://bjjs.zjw.beijing.gov.cn/eportal/ui?pageId=308894, why I can't find `json` type url as for this website? Could u please help take a look?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59856766/iterate-append-json-and-save-as-dataframe-in-python I create a new question here, please check it @ans2humna

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206428/discussion-between-ans2human-and-ahbon).