# Iterate append json and save as dataframe in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to iterate and extract tables from the link [here](http://zjj.sz.gov.cn/ztfw/gcjs/xmxx/jgysba/), then concatenate or append them to save as a dataframe.

I have used a loop iterate tables but I'm not sure how can I append all `json` or `dataframe` into one?

Anyone could help? Thank you.

```
from requests import post
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36",
        "Referer": "http://zjj.sz.gov.cn/projreg/public/jgys/jgysList.jsp"}
dfs = []
#dfs = pd.DataFrame()

for page in range(0, 5):
    data = {"limit": 100, "offset": page * 100, "pageNumber": page + 1}
    json_arr = requests.post("http://zjj.sz.gov.cn/projreg/public/jgys/webService/getJgysLogList.json", headers = headers, data = data).text
    d = json.loads(json_arr)
    df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(d['rows']) , orient='list')
```

Reference related: [Iterate and extract tables from web saving as excel file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59835094/iterate-and-extract-tables-from-web-saving-as-excel-file-in-python/59836064?noredirect=1#comment105840976_59836064)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html),

```py
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'http://zjj.sz.gov.cn/projreg/public/jgys/jgysList.jsp'
}

dfs = pd.DataFrame()

for page in range(0, 5):
    data = {'limit': 100, 'offset': page * 100, 'pageNumber': page + 1}
    json_arr = requests.post(
        'http://zjj.sz.gov.cn/projreg/public/jgys/webService/getJgysLogList.json', 
        headers=headers, 
        data=data).text
    d = json.loads(json_arr)
    df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(d['rows']) , orient='list')
    dfs = pd.concat([df, dfs], sort=False)
```

Or,

```py
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'http://zjj.sz.gov.cn/projreg/public/jgys/jgysList.jsp'
}

dfs = []

for page in range(0, 5):
    data = {'limit': 100, 'offset': page * 100, 'pageNumber': page + 1}
    json_arr = requests.post(
        'http://zjj.sz.gov.cn/projreg/public/jgys/webService/getJgysLogList.json', 
        headers=headers, 
        data=data).text
    d = json.loads(json_arr)
    dfs.append(pd.read_json(json.dumps(d['rows']) , orient='list'))

df = pd.concat(dfs, sort=False)
```

---

PS: The second block is much preferred as you should [never call DataFrame.append or pd.concat inside a for-loop. It leads to quadratic copying.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489576/why-does-concatenation-of-dataframes-get-exponentially-slower/36489724#36489724) Thanks [@parfait](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422451/parfait)!

Comment: `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

Comment: I think you forgot the expression `dfs = []`. Use `dfs = pd.DataFrame()` instead of `list`

Comment: The second block is much preferred as you should [never call DataFrame.append or pd.concat inside a for-loop. It leads to quadratic copying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/1422451).

Comment: That's absolutely true. If you allow me, I would like to add my answer. @Parfait