# Iterate pages and crawler HTML tables in Python

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I try to crawler the tables from this [link](http://bjjs.zjw.beijing.gov.cn/eportal/ui?pageId=308894), I have get position of table content by using **F12 inspect**.

[image]

I have use the follow code, but I get `None` result, someone could help? Thanks.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://bjjs.zjw.beijing.gov.cn/eportal/ui?pageId=308894'

website_url = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'gridview'})
#table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'criteria'})

print(table)
```

Please also check this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59835094/iterate-and-extract-tables-from-web-saving-as-excel-file-in-python/59836064?noredirect=1#comment105846105_59836064), in fact, I want do the similar things here, but the web structure seems different.

**Updated**:
The following code works for one page, but I need to loop other pages as well.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://bjjs.zjw.beijing.gov.cn/eportal/ui?pageId=308894'

website_url = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'gridview'})
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090632/python-excel-export
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index = False)
```

Output:

```
   序号  ...      竣工备案日期
0   1  ...  2020-01-22
1   2  ...  2020-01-22
2   3  ...  2020-01-22
3   4  ...  2020-01-22
4   5  ...  2020-01-22

[5 rows x 9 columns]
```

Reference related:

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/web-scraping-wiki-tables-using-beautifulsoup-and-python-6b9ea26d8722

Comment: Are you getting error or `print(table)` prints nothing ? When I try your code, It prints table elements

Comment: I only get `None`, did you modify anything?

Comment: Nope. I just copy and paste and it works @ahbon

Comment: By the way, there is typo in  `websit_url = requests.get(url).text`

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it, now it print the table's contents. Any ideas how can I extract them?

Comment: Can you check the answer ? Please Tell me if its true. Because I cant reach the website @ahbon

Comment: It's weird. Please try with this site, it's similar case. http://zfcj.gz.gov.cn/data/QueryService/Query.aspx?QueryID=6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get elements in `<tr>... </tr>` tags like :

```
table = soup.find_all('table', {'class': 'gridview'})

for elements in table:
    inner_elements = elements.findAll('tr')[1:]

    for text_for_elements in inner_elements:
        print(text_for_elements.text)
```

OUTPUT :

```
1
朝阳区东三环北路38号院4号楼3层301室内局部装修工程
威沃克办公服务（北京）有限公司
袁永懿
上海东园建筑装饰有限公司
陈振华
0065朝竣2020(装)0053号
北京市朝阳区住房和城乡建设委员会
2020-01-22
2
北京市朝阳区新源南路3号14层04单元A1704室内装修工程
重庆金融资产交易所有限责任公司
罗珊珊
深圳安星建设集团有限公司
张惠富
0066朝竣2020(装)0054号
北京市朝阳区住房和城乡建设委员会
2020-01-22
......
```

Comment: Thank you, please check my update. Do you know how to iterate other pages?

Comment: If you want to change pages by clicking to pagging  with code, You can use Python Selenium and webdriver. There are some examples on internet. I cant reach your website so I cant show

Comment: You can't open this one as well? http://zfcj.gz.gov.cn/data/QueryService/Query.aspx?QueryID=6

Comment: Sorry, Its blocked on my country.

Comment: Ok, I try it generates: `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'findAll'`.

Comment: How to convert it to dataframe?